# How to exchange data back and forth between two separate processes in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, queue, ipc

**PROBLEM**

There are two separate processes that run in parallel and I would like them to communicate back-and-forth.

**EXPLANATION OF THE CODE**

The code is in Python2.7. In my stripped to minimum script, I use a queue for between processes communication. The process p1 puts data in a queue. The process p2 gets the data from the queue and does something with the data. Then the process p2 puts the modified data back in the queue and finally then the process p1 gets back the modified data from the queue. The modified data must return to the process p1 because this process really is an eventlet server that sends/receives requests.

**CODE**

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7 python2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# script for back-and-forth data exchange between processes

# common modules
import os
import sys
import time
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing import Queue
from datetime import datetime

someData = {}

class Load():
    def post(self):
        timestamp = str(datetime.now())
        someData = {"process":"p1","class":"Load()","method":"post()","timestamp":timestamp}
        queue1.put(someData)        # put into queue
        print "#20 process 1: put in queue1 =>", someData
        time.sleep(3)

        while True:     # queue1 checking loop, comment out the loop if use time.sleep only
            if queue1.empty() == False:
                timestamp = str(datetime.now())
                res = queue1.get()
                res = {"process":"p1","class":"Load()","method":"post()","timestamp":timestamp}
                print "#28 get from queue1 =>", res
                break
            else:
                print "#31 queue1 empty"
                time.sleep(1)

        # while True:       # queue2 checking loop
        #   if queue2.empty() == False:
        #       timestamp = str(datetime.now())
        #       res = queue2.get()
        #       res = {"process":"p1","class":"Load()","method":"post()","timestamp":timestamp}
        #       print "#39 get from queue2 =>", res
        #       break
        #   else:
        #       print "#42 queue2 empty"
        #       time.sleep(1)

class Unload():
    def get(self):
        try:
            if queue1.empty() == False:
                data = queue1.get()     # retrieve package from queue
                #queue1.close()
                #queue1.join_thread()
                timestamp = str(datetime.now())
                data = {"process":"p2","class":"Unload()","method":"get()","timestamp":timestamp} 
                print "#54 process 2: get from queue1 =>", data
                self.doSomething(data)  # call method
            else:
                print "#57 queue1 empty"
                pass
        except:
            print "#60 queue1 error"
            pass

    def doSomething(self, data):
        time.sleep(3)
        timestamp = str(datetime.now())
        someData = {"process":"p2","class":"Unload()","method":"doSomething()","timestamp":timestamp}
        self.someData = someData
        print "#68 process 2: do something =>", someData
        self.put()

    def put(self):
        time.sleep(3)
        timestamp = str(datetime.now())
        self.someData = {"process":"p2","class":"Unload()","method":"put()","timestamp":timestamp}
        print "#75 process 2: put back in queue1 =>", self.someData
        res = self.someData
        queue1.put(res)
        #print "#78 process 2: put back in queue2 =>", self.someData
        #res = self.someData
        #queue2.put(res)
        #queue2.close()
        #queue2.join_thread()

# main 
if __name__ == '__main__':

    queue1 = Queue()
    #queue2 = Queue()

    global p1, p2
    p1 = Process(target=Load().post(), args=(queue1,))      # process p1
    #p1 = Process(target=Load().post(), args=(queue1,queue2,))
    p1.daemon = True
    p1.start() 

    p2 = Process(target=Unload().get(), args=(queue1,))     # process p2
    #p2 = Process(target=Unload().get(), args=(queue1,queue2,))
    p2.start()
    p2.join()
```

**QUESTION**
I have checked other resources in regard but they all involve one direction communication. Below is the list of resources.

1. [use-get-nowait-in-python-without-raising-empty-exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39170249/use-get-nowait-in-python-without-raising-empty-exception)
2. [in-python-how-do-you-get-data-back-from-a-particular-process-using-multiprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11216702/in-python-how-do-you-get-data-back-from-a-particular-process-using-multiprocess)
3. [how-to-use-multiprocessing-queue-with-lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57095895/how-to-use-multiprocessing-queue-with-lock)
4. [multiprocessing module supports locks](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2016/08/02/python-201-a-multiprocessing-tutorial/)
5. [thread-that-i-can-pause-and-resume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33640283/thread-that-i-can-pause-and-resume)
6. [exchange-data-between-two-python-processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45066782/exchange-data-between-two-python-processes)

How do I get the process1 to wait and retrieve the modified data from process2? Should I consider another approach for the communication between processes e.g pipes, zeroMQ?

**ATTEMPT 1: using time.sleep() without the while loops in process 1**
With only the time.sleep the data go up to back in the queue but never reach the final  destination in process 1. So far so good but the final step is missing. The results are below.

```
#20 process 1: put in queue1 => {'process': 'p1', 'timestamp': '2020-02-23 11:40:30.234466', 'class': 'Load()', 'method': 'post()'}
#54 process 2: get from queue1 => {'process': 'p2', 'timestamp': '2020-02-23 11:40:33.239113', 'class': 'Unload()', 'method': 'get()'}
#68 process 2: do something => {'process': 'p2', 'timestamp': '2020-02-23 11:40:36.242500', 'class': 'Unload()', 'method': 'doSomething()'}
#75 process 2: put back in queue1 => {'process': 'p2', 'timestamp': '2020-02-23 11:40:39.245856', 'class': 'Unload()', 'method': 'put()'}
```

**ATTEMPT 2: using the while loop in process 1**
With the while loop checking the queue the data go in the queue but get caught right after, they never reach the process 2. The results are below.

```
#20 process 1: put in queue1 => {'process': 'p1', 'timestamp': '2020-02-23 11:46:14.606356', 'class': 'Load()', 'method': 'post()'}
#28 get from queue1 => {'process': 'p1', 'timestamp': '2020-02-23 11:46:17.610202', 'class': 'Load()', 'method': 'post()'}
#57 queue1 empty
```

**ATTEMPT 3: using two queues**
Using two queues: queue1 from process1 to process2, queue2 from process2 to process1. The data go in the queue1 but do not return in queue2, they mysteriously vanish. The results are below.

```
#20 process 1: put in queue1 => {'process': 'p1', 'timestamp': '2020-02-23 11:53:39.745177', 'class': 'Load()', 'method': 'post()'}
#42 queue2 empty
```

**----- UPDATE 20200224: attempts 4, 5 and 6 -----------------------------------------------------------------**

**ATTEMPT 4: using two queues with manager.Queue()**

Using two queues with the manager.Queue(): queue1 from process1 to process2, queue2 from process2 to process1. The data go in the queue1 but do not return in queue2, again they mysteriously vanish. The code and results are below.

The code of the attempt 4:
    #!/usr/bin/python2.7 python2.7
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    # script for serialized interprocess data exchange

```
# common modules
import os
import sys
import time
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing import Queue
from multiprocessing import Manager
from datetime import datetime

someData = {}
manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
queue1 = manager.Queue()
queue2 = manager.Queue()

class Load():
    def post(self):
        timestamp = str(datetime.now())
        someData = {"process":"p1","class":"Load()","method":"post()","timestamp":timestamp}
        queue1.put(someData)        # put into queue
        print "#20 process 1: put in queue1 =>", someData
        time.sleep(3)

        # while True:       # queue1 checking loop
        #   if queue1.empty() == False:
        #       timestamp = str(datetime.now())
        #       res = queue1.get()
        #       res = {"process":"p1","class":"Load()","method":"post()","timestamp":timestamp}
        #       print "#28 get from queue1 =>", res
        #       break
        #   else:
        #       print "#31 queue1 empty"
        #       time.sleep(1)

        while True:     # queue2 checking loop
            if queue2.empty() == False:
                timestamp = str(datetime.now())
                res = queue2.get()
                res = {"process":"p1","class":"Load()","method":"post()","timestamp":timestamp}
                print "#39 get from queue2 =>", res
                break
            else:
                print "#42 queue2 empty"
                time.sleep(1)

class Unload():
    def get(self):
        try:
            if queue1.empty() == False:
                data = queue1.get()     # retrieve package from queue
                #queue1.close()
                #queue1.join_thread()
                timestamp = str(datetime.now())
                data = {"process":"p2","class":"Unload()","method":"get()","timestamp":timestamp} 
                print "#54 process 2: get from queue1 =>", data
                self.doSomething(data)  # call method
            else:
                print "#57 queue1 empty"
                pass
        except:
            print "#60 queue1 error"
            pass

    def doSomething(self, data):
        time.sleep(3)
        timestamp = str(datetime.now())
        someData = {"process":"p2","class":"Unload()","method":"doSomething()","timestamp":timestamp}
        self.someData = someData
        print "#68 process 2: do something =>", someData
        self.put()

    def put(self):
        time.sleep(3)
        timestamp = str(datetime.now())
        self.someData = {"process":"p2","class":"Unload()","method":"put()","timestamp":timestamp}
        res = self.someData
        #print "#75 process 2: put back in queue1 =>", self.someData
        #queue1.put(res)
        print "#78 process 2: put back in queue2 =>", self.someData
        queue2.put(res)
        #queue2.close()
        #queue2.join_thread()

# main 
if __name__ == '__main__':

    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    queue1 = manager.Queue()
    queue2 = manager.Queue()

    global p1, p2
    #p1 = Process(target=Load().post(), args=(queue1,))     # process p1
    p1 = Process(target=Load().post(), args=(queue1,queue2,))
    p1.daemon = True
    p1.start() 

    #p2 = Process(target=Unload().get(), args=(queue1,))        # process p2
    p2 = Process(target=Unload().get(), args=(queue1,queue2,))
    p2.start()
    p2.join()
```

The results of the attempt 4:

```
#20 process 1: put in queue1 => {'process': 'p1', 'timestamp': '2020-02-24 13:06:17.687762', 'class': 'Load()', 'method': 'post()'}
#42 queue2 empty
```

**ATTEMPT 5: using one queue with manager.Queue()**
Using one queue with the manager.Queue(): queue1 from process1 to process2, queue1 back from process2 to process1. The data go in the queue1 but get caught right after, they never reach the process 2. The code results are below.

The code of the attempt 5:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7 python2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# script for serialized interprocess data exchange

# common modules
import os
import sys
import time
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing import Queue
from multiprocessing import Manager
from datetime import datetime

someData = {}
manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
queue1 = manager.Queue()
#queue2 = manager.Queue()

class Load():
    def post(self):
        timestamp = str(datetime.now())
        someData = {"process":"p1","class":"Load()","method":"post()","timestamp":timestamp}
        queue1.put(someData)        # put into queue
        print "#25 process 1: put in queue1 =>", someData
        time.sleep(3)

        while True:     # queue1 checking loop
            if queue1.empty() == False:
                timestamp = str(datetime.now())
                res = queue1.get()
                res = {"process":"p1","class":"Load()","method":"post()","timestamp":timestamp}
                print "#33 get from queue1 =>", res
                break
            else:
                print "#36 queue1 empty"
                time.sleep(1)

        # while True:       # queue2 checking loop
        #   if queue2.empty() == False:
        #       timestamp = str(datetime.now())
        #       res = queue2.get()
        #       res = {"process":"p1","class":"Load()","method":"post()","timestamp":timestamp}
        #       print "#44 get from queue2 =>", res
        #       break
        #   else:
        #       print "#47 queue2 empty"
        #       time.sleep(1)

class Unload():
    def get(self):
        try:
            if queue1.empty() == False:
                data = queue1.get()     # retrieve package from queue
                #queue1.close()
                #queue1.join_thread()
                timestamp = str(datetime.now())
                data = {"process":"p2","class":"Unload()","method":"get()","timestamp":timestamp} 
                print "#59 process 2: get from queue1 =>", data
                self.doSomething(data)  # call method
            else:
                print "#62 queue1 empty"
                pass
        except:
            print "#65 queue1 error"
            pass

    def doSomething(self, data):
        time.sleep(3)
        timestamp = str(datetime.now())
        someData = {"process":"p2","class":"Unload()","method":"doSomething()","timestamp":timestamp}
        self.someData = someData
        print "#73 process 2: do something =>", someData
        self.put()

    def put(self):
        time.sleep(3)
        timestamp = str(datetime.now())
        self.someData = {"process":"p2","class":"Unload()","method":"put()","timestamp":timestamp}
        res = self.someData
        print "#81 process 2: put back in queue1 =>", self.someData
        queue1.put(res)
        #print "#83 process 2: put back in queue2 =>", self.someData
        #queue2.put(res)
        #queue2.close()
        #queue2.join_thread()

# main 
if __name__ == '__main__':

    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    queue1 = manager.Queue()
    #queue2 = manager.Queue()

    global p1, p2
    p1 = Process(target=Load().post(), args=(queue1,))      # process p1
    #p1 = Process(target=Load().post(), args=(queue1,queue2,))
    p1.daemon = True
    p1.start() 

    p2 = Process(target=Unload().get(), args=(queue1,))     # process p2
    #p2 = Process(target=Unload().get(), args=(queue1,queue2,))
    p2.start()
    p2.join()
```

The result of the attempt 5:

```
#25 process 1: put in queue1 => {'process': 'p1', 'timestamp': '2020-02-24 14:08:13.975886', 'class': 'Load()', 'method': 'post()'}
#33 get from queue1 => {'process': 'p1', 'timestamp': '2020-02-24 14:08:16.980382', 'class': 'Load()', 'method': 'post()'}
#62 queue1 empty
```

**ATTEMPT 6: using the queue timeouts**

As suggested I tried to correct the queue timeouts. The approach is again queue1 from process1 to process2, queue2 from process2 to process1. The data go in the queue1 but do not return in queue2, again they mysteriously vanish. The code and results are below.

The code of the attempt 6:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7 python2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# script for serialized interprocess data exchange

# common modules
import os
import sys
import time
import uuid
import Queue
#from Queue import Empty
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Process
#from multiprocessing import Queue
from datetime import datetime

someData = {}

class Load():
    def post(self):
        timestamp = str(datetime.now())
        someData = {"process":"p1","class":"Load()","method":"post()","timestamp":timestamp}
        queue1.put(someData)        # put into queue
        print "#24 process 1: put in queue1 =>", someData
        time.sleep(3)

        # while True:       # queue1 checking loop
        #   if queue1.empty() == False:
        #       timestamp = str(datetime.now())
        #       res = queue1.get()
        #       res = {"process":"p1","class":"Load()","method":"post()","timestamp":timestamp}
        #       print "#33 get from queue1 =>", res
        #       break
        #   else:
        #       print "#36 queue1 empty"
        #       time.sleep(1)

        while True:     # queue2 checking loop
            try:
                someData = queue2.get(True,1)
                timestamp = str(datetime.now())
                someData = {"process":"p1","class":"Load()","method":"post()","timestamp":timestamp}
                print "#43 process 1: got from queue2 =>", someData
                break
            except Queue.Empty:
                print "#46 process1: queue2 empty"
                continue

class Unload():
    def get(self):
        while True:     # queue2 checking loop
            try:
                someData = queue1.get(True,1)
                timestamp = str(datetime.now())
                someData = {"process":"p2","class":"Unload()","method":"get()","timestamp":timestamp} 
                print "#56 process2: got from queue1 =>", someData
                break
            except Queue.Empty:
                print "#59 process2: queue1 empty"
                continue
        self.doSomething(someData)  # call method

    def doSomething(self, data):
        time.sleep(3)
        timestamp = str(datetime.now())
        someData = {"process":"p2","class":"Unload()","method":"doSomething()","timestamp":timestamp}
        self.someData = someData
        print "#68 process2: do something =>", someData
        self.put(someData)

    def put(self,data):
        time.sleep(3)
        timestamp = str(datetime.now())
        self.someData = {"process":"p2","class":"Unload()","method":"put()","timestamp":timestamp}
        someData = self.someData
        #print "#81 process 2: put back in queue1 =>", self.someData
        #queue1.put(res)
        print "#78 process2: put back in queue2 =>", someData
        queue2.put(someData)


# main 
if __name__ == '__main__':

    queue1 = multiprocessing.Queue()
    queue2 = multiprocessing.Queue()

    global p1, p2
    #p1 = Process(target=Load().post(), args=(queue1,))     # process p1
    p1 = Process(target=Load().post(), args=(queue1,queue2,))
    p1.daemon = True
    p1.start() 

    #p2 = Process(target=Unload().get(), args=(queue1,))        # process p2
    p2 = Process(target=Unload().get(), args=(queue1,queue2,))
    p2.start()
    p2.join()
```

The results of the attempt 6:

```
#24 process 1: put in queue1 => {'process': 'p1', 'timestamp': '2020-02-24 18:14:46.435661', 'class': 'Load()', 'method': 'post()'}
#46 process1: queue2 empty
```

NOTE: The suggested approach works when I use it without the classes. The code is below:

```
import uuid
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Process
import Queue


def load(que_in, que_out):
    request = {"id": uuid.uuid4(), "workload": "do_stuff", }
    que_in.put(request)
    print("load: sent request {}: {}".format(request["id"], request["workload"]))
    while True:
        try:
            result = que_out.get(True, 1)
        except Queue.Empty:
            continue
        print("load: got result {}: {}".format(result["id"], result["result"]))


def unload(que_in, que_out):
    def processed(request):
        return {"id": request["id"], "result": request["workload"] + " processed", }
    while True:
        try:
            request = que_in.get(True, 1)
        except Queue.Empty:
            continue
        print("unload: got request {}: {}".format(request["id"], request["workload"]))
        result = processed(request)
        que_out.put(result)
        print("unload: sent result {}: {}".format(result["id"], result["result"]))


    # main
if __name__ == '__main__':

    que_in = multiprocessing.Queue()
    que_out = multiprocessing.Queue()

    p1 = Process(target=load, args=(que_in, que_out))      # process p1
    p1.daemon = True
    p1.start()

    p2 = Process(target=unload, args=(que_in, que_out))     # process p2
    p2.start()
    p2.join()
```

**----- UPDATE 20200225: attempt 7 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

**ATTEMPT 7: using one queue with queue timeouts in different classes (working)**

In this attempt I use one shared queue between methods of different classes with the corrected timeouts. The data goes from process1 to process2 and back from process2 to process1 in a shared_queue. In this attempt the data travelled correctly. The code and results are below.

The code of the attempt 7:

```
import uuid
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Process
import Queue

class Input():
    def load(self, shared_queue):
        request = {"id": uuid.uuid4(), "workload": "do_stuff", }
        shared_queue.put(request)
        print("load: sent request {}: {}".format(request["id"], request["workload"]))
        while True:
            try:
                result = shared_queue.get(True, 1)
            except Queue.Empty:
                continue
            print("load: got result {}: {}".format(result["id"], result["result"]))
            break

class Output():
    def unload(self, shared_queue):
        def processed(request):
            return {"id": request["id"], "result": request["workload"] + " processed", }
        while True:
            try:
                request = shared_queue.get(True, 1)
            except Queue.Empty:
                continue
            print("unload: got request {}: {}".format(request["id"], request["workload"]))
            result = processed(request)
            shared_queue.put(result)
            print("unload: sent result {}: {}".format(result["id"], result["result"]))


    # main
if __name__ == '__main__':

    shared_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    up = Input()
    down = Output()

    p1 = Process(target=up.load, args=(shared_queue,))      # process p1
    p1.daemon = True
    p1.start()


    p2 = Process(target=down.unload, args=(shared_queue,))     # process p2
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

The results of the attempt 7:

```
load: sent request a461357a-b39a-43c4-89a8-a77486a5bf45: do_stuff
unload: got request a461357a-b39a-43c4-89a8-a77486a5bf45: do_stuff
unload: sent result a461357a-b39a-43c4-89a8-a77486a5bf45: do_stuff processed
load: got result a461357a-b39a-43c4-89a8-a77486a5bf45: do_stuff processed
```

Comment: What happened to attempt 3?

Comment: @AnthonyKong, I updated the attempt 3 explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION: using one shared queue**

I solved the problem after following the suggestions and making some adjustments getting the right targeting of the different classes methods. The back and forth flow of the data between two separate processes is now correct. An important note for me is to pay extra attention to the `someData` package exchanged between two separate processes, it really has to be the same package that is tossed around. Hence the identifier entry `"id": uuid.uuid4()` to check if the package is the same with every passage.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7 python2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# script for back and forth communication between two separate processes using a shared queue

# common modules
import os
import sys
import time
import uuid
import Queue
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Process
from datetime import datetime


someData = {}


class Load():
    def post(self, sharedQueue):
        timestamp = str(datetime.now()) # for timing checking
        someData = {"timestamp":timestamp, "id": uuid.uuid4(), "workload": "do_stuff",}
        self.someData = someData
        sharedQueue.put(someData)       # put into the shared queue
        print("#25 p1 load: sent someData {}: {}".format(someData["id"], someData["timestamp"], someData["workload"]))
        time.sleep(1)   # for the time flow     

        while True:     # sharedQueue checking loop
            try:
                time.sleep(1)   # for the time flow
                timestamp = str(datetime.now())
                someData = sharedQueue.get(True,1)
                someData["timestamp"] = timestamp
                print("#37 p1 load: got back someData {}: {}".format(someData["id"], someData["timestamp"], someData["workload"]))
                break
            except Queue.Empty:
                print("#37 p1: sharedQueue empty")
                continue
            break


class Unload():
    def get(self, sharedQueue):
        while True:     # sharedQueue checking loop
            try:
                someData = sharedQueue.get(True,1)
                self.someData = someData
                timestamp = str(datetime.now())
                someData["timestamp"] = timestamp
                print("#50 p2 unload: got someData {}: {}".format(someData["id"], someData["timestamp"], someData["workload"]))
                break
            except Queue.Empty:
                print("#53 p2: sharedQueue empty")
                continue
        time.sleep(1)               # for the time flow
        self.doSomething(someData)  # pass the data to the method


    def doSomething(self, someData):    # execute some code here
        timestamp = str(datetime.now())
        someData["timestamp"] = timestamp
        print("#62 p2 unload: doSomething {}: {}".format(someData["id"], someData["timestamp"], someData["workload"]))
        self.put(someData)
        time.sleep(1)   # for the time flow


    def put(self,someData):
        timestamp = str(datetime.now())
        someData["timestamp"] = timestamp
        sharedQueue.put(someData)
        print("#71 p2 unload: put someData {}: {}".format(someData["id"], someData["timestamp"], someData["workload"]))
        time.sleep(1)   # for the time flow


# main 
if __name__ == '__main__':

    sharedQueue = multiprocessing.Queue()

    trx = Load()
    rcx = Unload()

    p1 = Process(target=trx.post, args=(sharedQueue,))      # process p1
    p1.daemon = True
    p1.start() 

    p2 = Process(target=rcx.get, args=(sharedQueue,))       # process p2
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just missed queue timeouts usage

```
try:
    result = que_out.get(True, 1)
except queue.Empty:
    continue
```

This simplified example may help you:

```
import uuid
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing import Queue
import queue


def load(que_in, que_out):
    request = {"id": uuid.uuid4(), "workload": "do_stuff", }
    que_in.put(request)
    print("load: sent request {}: {}".format(request["id"], request["workload"]))
    while True:
        try:
            result = que_out.get(True, 1)
        except queue.Empty:
            continue
        print("load: got result {}: {}".format(result["id"], result["result"]))


def unload(que_in, que_out):

    def processed(request):
        return {"id": request["id"], "result": request["workload"] + " processed", }

    while True:
        try:
            request = que_in.get(True, 1)
        except queue.Empty:
            continue
        print("unload: got request {}: {}".format(request["id"], request["workload"]))
        result = processed(request)
        que_out.put(result)
        print("unload: sent result {}: {}".format(result["id"], result["result"]))

    # main
if __name__ == '__main__':

    que_in = Queue()
    que_out = Queue()

    p1 = Process(target=load, args=(que_in, que_out))      # process p1
    p1.daemon = True
    p1.start()

    p2 = Process(target=unload, args=(que_in, que_out))     # process p2
    p2.start()
    p2.join()
```

Output

```
load: sent request d9894e41-3e8a-4474-9563-1a99797bc722: do_stuff
unload: got request d9894e41-3e8a-4474-9563-1a99797bc722: do_stuff
unload: sent result d9894e41-3e8a-4474-9563-1a99797bc722: do_stuff processed
load: got result d9894e41-3e8a-4474-9563-1a99797bc722: do_stuff processed
```

Comment: This simplified example of yours, @Man-In wholeEarthMan, works in Python3 and with minor changes also in Python2. Still I am not able to run the code when the methods `load` and `unload` belong to two separate classes.

Comment: what the problem? is it on python2?

Comment: Yes @Man-In, the code is written in Python 2.7. With some minor adjustments I made it work. The issue was elsewhere, I was incorrectly targeting the classes methods.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Manager-wrapped queue(s) to propagate changes across processes, otherwise each process has its separate queue object and can't see the other one(s). Manager creates a shared instance of the queue for all children processes.

So `queue1 = Queue()` becomes `queue1 = manager.Queue()` with `from multiprocessing import Manager` at the top. If you want to use your two queues approach, you obviously have to wrap the second queue in the same way.

Relevant resources:

[Multiple queues from one multiprocessing Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50869656/multiple-queues-from-one-multiprocessing-manager/50934524)

[Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#managers)

Comment: In the attempts 4 and 5 I tried with `manager.Queue()` as suggested by @adq but got same results as in the attempts 2 and 3. I updated my question with the code and results of the attempts 4 and 5.